# using python3 libs in ros kinetic

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, ros

I am working with project, connected with ROS Kinetic. I wrote my nodes, using Python3 and tried to transfer some information with ros-service from 1 node to another. This information represents a huge object that couldn't be easilly formatted to normal ROS types, so I used `pickle.dumps(object, 0).decode()` and send it like a string.In the server side I couldn't use pickle and met an exception about: `No module named search`.
The code of the server side:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from visualization.srv import *
import rospy
import pickle

megafoo = []

def handle_nodes(req):
    global megafoo
    print(type(req.nodes))
    megafoo.extend(pickle.loads(req.nodes.encode()))
    print(len(megafoo))
    a=1
    print("A request type: {0}".format(type(req)))
    return ListNodesResponse(a)

def nodes_creater_server():
    rospy.init_node('nodes_server')
    s = rospy.Service('draw_some_nodes', ListNodes, handle_nodes)
    print('ready to draw nodes')
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nodes_creater_server()
```

I tried to make this without calling pickle and problem was resolved so I think that I can't call pickle from server somehow

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to the party, but "No module named search" sounds like your pickle string contains a custom class "search" that isn't available at the receiving side. Would this be correct?

To verify you can try to transfer some simple native Python value like (123, "abc") using pickle in ROS (which should work).
Another option is to write two separate programs, one that writes the pickle to disk, and another one that reads the pickle from that file. Then you can experiment with loading, and eg decide which modules you need to import.